# If there are no arrays for css, how do I organize many similar entries?

Tags: css

Sorry for the question wording.  It kept complaining it was subjecting and would be deleted.

I going to have several hundred entries like this:

```
span#CNQM {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_CNQM.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#HKBAM {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_HKBAM.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#SWBAM {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_SWBAM.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#DEAM2 {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_DEAM2.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#SFCQM1 {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_SFCQM1.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#SFCQM2 {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_SFCQM2.png) no-repeat top left;
}
span#SFCQM3 {
    background: url(../../../../images/icons/sfc_SFCQM3.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

And it is getting a little unwieldy.

Is there a better way in CSS to handle this vs. maintaining a mega-list?  In a scripting language, I'd make an array (CNQM, HKBAM, SWBAM, etc) and loop through them.

I'm perfectly OK with the answer being "its just the way it is", but if there is a better way, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Comment: You could use a scripting language to build your CSS

Comment: can confirm the @DrydenLong 's comment. You can use js or php for example...

Comment: Using a scripting language to build the CSS would be fine if you then save the CSS that it generates instead of generating that every time the page loads. I would recommend making another class for the repetitive poperties like `no-repeat` and `top left`. You can look into CSS SASS and CSS LESS. They compile CSS based on some rules you write. They support lists which will compile into the CSS file you use.

Comment: You could also solve this with Javascript. For the CSS you show, you must have `<span id="SFCQM2">` and such. Add a class to all of these: `<span class="bgnd" id="SFCQM2">` then, on dom-ready, select everything with class "bgnd", get the ID for each, and build the background url from that. This does, however, put the load on the browser and can give you a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't solve this problem in CSS. That's why [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) were invented. Use one of those.

Comment: Agreed.  SASS offers loops and variables, which make managing sets of information much easier.  Here's a good tutorial: http://benfrain.com/working-with-lists-and-each-loops-in-sass-with-the-index-and-nth-function/

Comment: Once upon a time I did take a brief look at those.  At the time, they seemed far too complicated to bother with for my needs.  Time to look again, so thanks for the nudge.